# Developing python software that will run in different environment

Tags: python, slurm

I have the last six months been working on a Python GUI application that I will use at work. Specifically my GUI will run on a couple of super computer clusters that I use for work.

However, I am mostly developing the software at my personal computer, and here I do not have direct access to the commands that my GUI will call, since the GUI will use `subprocess` to call commands that only are available on the computing cluster.

So, in order to efficiently develop the program, I often have to copy the directory containing all files related to the GUI, to the cluster. Then I test my current version there, locate all my bugs, fix them by editing the files on the cluster, and finally copy back all files to my computer, overwriting the old version.

This just seems like a bad way of doing it, but I have to be able to test my software in the environment it is made for in order to find my bugs.

Surely this is a common problem in software development... What do actual programmers do (as opposed to hobby programmers such as myself)?

Edit:
Examples of commands that are only available on the computing cluster, that I make heavy use of, are `squeue`, `sacct`, and `scontrol` (SLURM related commands).

Edit2:
I could mention that I tested using ssh connections with Python, but it slowed down the commands significantly, having to establish the ssh connection for each command I wanted. Unless I could set of a lasting ssh session, as in logging in when opening my program, I don't think the ssh-ing will work.

Comment: what do u want to be cross platform, like making dirs or getting  user home location etc?

Comment: Slurm specific commands, such as `squeue` or `sacct` or `scontrol` are only available on the cluster.

Comment: At first sight I would say: use Git. With a central repo accessible from both your workstation and the cluster, you won't have to copy but to clone/pull/push. And you'll benefit of code versioning, which really is something you want when developing software.
Another thing you could do is using a virtual environment, once again accessible from both your workstation and cluster. I do this with `conda` which allows to test using the same Python and main dependencies wherever I activate the environment, but to benefit from specific local context on some machines (like an HPC).

Comment: this rather sounds like use case for [Vagrant](https://www.vagrantup.com)

Comment: We use git to synchronize our repo's in Slurm. The workflow is something like: code in local machine; push; access remote cluster using SSH; pull updates; run `sbatch` with script preparing the environment, updating conda, and running the script.

Answer (score 1):

Explore the concepts that make [Vagrant a popular choice for developers](https://www.vagrantup.com/intro/index.html#for-developers)

> Vagrant is a tool for building and managing virtual machine
>   environments in a single workflow. With an easy-to-use workflow and
>   focus on automation, Vagrant lowers development environment setup
>   time, increases production parity, and makes the "works on my machine"
>   excuse a relic of the past.

Your use case is covered by a couple of vagrant boxes that create a slurm cluster for development purposes. A good starting point might be

- [Example slurm cluster on your laptop (multiple VMs via vagrant)](http://jandomanski.blogspot.com/2016/11/experimental-slurm-cluster-on-vagrant.html)

If you understand and can setup your development environment with tools like Vagrant, you might explore next which options modern code editors or integrated development environments (IDE) offer for remote development. Remote development covers some other use cases, that might fit into your developer toolbox as well.

A "good enough", free and open source code editor for Python development is Visual Studio Code. According to the docs it has powerful features for remote development.

> Visual Studio Code Remote Development allows you to use a container, remote machine, or the Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL) as a full-featured development environment.

Read the docs

- [VS Code Remote Development](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/remote-overview)